# A mysql_fetch_array in another

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, fetch

I've seen the question about "doing mysql_fetch_array" multiple times solved by stocking the result in another variable, or by resetting the mysql_fetch_array loop index for example...

But that's not what I need. I need to use 2 mysql_fetch_ array, **one in another**, like this :

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT step FROM cyclone_cities ORDER BY uid");
$inc = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql,MYSQL_NUM)){
    $selected = $row[0];
    while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT ".$selected." FROM cyclone_players ORDER BY uid"))){
        print_r($row2);
    }
}
```

How can I make it to use two differents mysql_fetch_array indexes ?

Comment: Perhaps it's easier if you just use a `JOIN` in the first query, and just have one query. What do you mean by "*How can I make it to use two differents mysql_fetch_array indexes ?*" though?

Comment: I'm afraid that by using a mysql_fetch_array that is indexing some way inside another that is indexing another way, I might melt them together or just do mess. This seems very unsafe however. Hows can I use join ?

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices.

Comment: Well, that doesn't answer my question at all.